# Trying to remove a child html element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 tables in my boostrap tab. Each tab as a table. The rows of this table is dynamically generated with csharp asp.net code. Right I Want a scenario were if a user click on the row of the first table, the clicked role of the first table get remove from the first table and is added to the rows of the second table.

My challenge as been getting to remove the row after the onClick process.

```
 <tbody>
     <tr id="kayode@yahoo.com">
                     <td> kayode <a class="chat" connectionid="135976e6-799b-4cda-a764-a00f7110d515"
 data-parentid="kayode@yahoo.com"
 href="/Visitor/StartChat?threadid=3&amp;email=kayode%40yahoo.com"
 operatorid="1" target="_blank" threadid="3">chat</a></td>
                     <td>271.0.0.1</td>
                     <td>Active</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>9/13/2014</td>
                     <td>04:15:18</td>
                     <td>02:52:55</td>
                     <td>271.0.0.1</td>
                 </tr>

</tbody>
```

My javascript code which I am trying to use to remove the row after the Click event.

```
function updateWaitingState(sender) {

        var parentid = $(sender).attr("data-parentid");
        //alert(parentid);

        //we are going to remove the role from this field
        var element = document.getElementById(parentid);

         element.parentNode.removeChild(element);   //This line is a problem says 

        //document.querySelector("tablebody4 first").appendChild(element);

        console.log(element);
 }
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and pure DOM APIs? Seems your requirements can be done simply by `$('#table1').on('click', 'tr', function(){ $(this).appendTo('#table2'); });`

Comment: watch these free tutorials to learn jquery please http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-jquery

Comment: btw there is only one row do you want that row to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function updateWaitingState(sender) {

        var parentid = $(sender).attr("data-parentid");

        var element = document.getElementById(parentid);
        $(element).appendTo('.tablebody2:first');
 }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe This DOES answer the question.  This is the solution the OP says works.

Comment: The answer I pasted works. I love to says a big thankyou to all the posters. @cory you were close but I had a problem using the parent tag and appending. So I used the document.getElement...... which works better.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I imagine jQuery will greatly reduce your headache here:

```
function updateWaitingState(sender) {
    var parentId = $(sender).attr("data-parentid");
    $('#' + parentId).appendTo('.tablebody4:first');
}
```

You may need to adjust the selector in the `appendTo` function, as it was a guess on my part.

Comment: Well jquery wont work because I found it difficult getting id in jquery so I used javascript. Could you give me equivalent in javascript